# How to group count of a column by weeks in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code which groups data by month.

```
select project_name, to_char (date_sys, 'Month') as Month, sum(BATCH.RECORDS_NUMBER) as Count_of_Documents
 from 
    BATCH
    group by project_name, to_char(date_sys, 'Month');
```

I am wanting to group by week now as following:

```
+------------+-------+
|week        | Count |
+------------+-------+
| 2016-12-05 |    14 |
| 2016-12-12 |    20 |
| 2016-12-19 |    19 |
| 2016-12-26 |    15 |
| 2017-01-02 |    13 |
| 2017-01-09 |    14 |
| 2017-01-16 |    12 |
| 2017-01-23 |    12 |
| 2017-01-30 |     5 |
```

date_format and datepart do not seem to work with Oracle SQL as I get "ORA-00904: “DATE_FORMAT”: invalid identifier" error. I was wondering if anyone can help with the code. I'd also appreciate if it can be sorted by daily counts. Thank you

Comment: What do you consider as "week", I.e. which is the first day of the week?

Comment: I'd like the first day of the week to be 'Sunday'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `TRUNC` instead of `TO_CHAR`, because when your data spans over more than a year, then it will group several years into one record.

```
select project_name, to_char(TRUNC(date_sys, 'MM'), 'Month') as Month,      
   sum(BATCH.RECORDS_NUMBER) as Count_of_Documents
from BATCH
group by project_name, TRUNC(date_sys, 'MM');
```

Assuming you want to group by week according to ISO-8601 standard use

```
select project_name, to_char(TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW'), 'YYYY-"W"IW') as WEEK,      
   sum(BATCH.RECORDS_NUMBER) as Count_of_Documents
from BATCH
group by project_name, TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW');
```

If you like to start your week on Sunday, then you can use

```
select project_name, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(date_sys+1, 'IW')-1, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as week,       
   sum(BATCH.RECORDS_NUMBER) as Count_of_Documents
from BATCH
group by project_name, TRUNC(date_sys+1, 'IW');
```

You can also group by starting day of the week, `'D'`. Be aware, the output of `TRUNC(date_sys, 'D')` depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY` settings, so the output might be not consistent.

See [ROUND and TRUNC Date Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html)

Comment: This seems to work but for the week column the rows are displaying "2022-W50" , "2022-W44." Is there a way I can display a week start day instead? For example: 11/29/2022?

Comment: Just replace `'YYYY-"W"IW'` with the format you desire, e.g. `'MM/DD/YYYY'`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the week number of the year using [ISO week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) or, if you want that week 1 starts on the first day of year, then use the second option below 'ww':

```sql
WITH
    dates AS
        (   Select 
                To_Date('01.01.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') + (LEVEL - 1) + ((LEVEL - 1)*2) "A_DATE"
            From Dual 
            Connect By LEVEL <= 9   )
Select
    A_DATE,
    To_Char(A_DATE, 'IW') "ISO_WEEK_NO",
    To_Char(A_DATE, 'ww') "WW_WEEK_NO"
From dates
```

R e s u l t :

| A_DATE | ISO_WEEK_NO | WW_WEEK_NO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-22 | 52 | 01 |
| 04-JAN-22 | 01 | 01 |
| 07-JAN-22 | 01 | 01 |
| 10-JAN-22 | 02 | 02 |
| 13-JAN-22 | 02 | 02 |
| 16-JAN-22 | 02 | 03 |
| 19-JAN-22 | 03 | 03 |
| 22-JAN-22 | 03 | 04 |
| 25-JAN-22 | 04 | 04 |

Do the Group By using one of the above week numbers like you did it by months.

And if you want Sunday here is how to get the date of Sunday week before today:

```sql
SELECT NEXT_DAY (SYSDATE - 4, 'SUNDAY') - 7 "SUNDAY_WEEK_BEFORE" FROM dual
--  
--  SUNDAY_WEEK_BEFORE
--  ------------------
--  11-DEC-22
```